# Submit a form and get a JSON response with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

any idea how to get a get the JSON response from server after posting a Form
I want to post some info, email,pass,confirmation then I want to send the passed email back to frontend.
so I can use it later to verify a pin any idea how to grab the response right after posting using JS?

```js
// Backend code 
exports.signUp = async (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body);
res.status(200).json({Email : req.body.Email});
})

// Frontend code
 <form class="modal-content" method='POST' action="/sign" >
        <div class="container">
          <hr>
          <label for="email" ><b>Email</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email">
          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="Password" required>
          <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
          <input id="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="PasswordConfirm" required>
 </form>
 
 // outgoing data model from Frontend after post
 { Email: 'Email@email.com', Password: '0', PasswordConfirm: '0' }
```

Comment: You're looking for AJAX apparently (making a request to the server in the background). Use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for that.

Comment: can a fetch accept an incoming request without the need to request to server ? since I want to send the response back anyway ?

Comment: fetch() is used to make an HTTP request to the server. You would usually use GET or POST, and URL params or body data accordingly. The server can send back arbitrary data which your frontend can process. I have no idea what you are referring to in your comment, a fetch cannot accept a request in any sense. HTTP requests are always intitiated from the client (i.e. the frontend) and answered by the server.

Comment: thanks Chirs I will remember that (new to backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way: use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
 
  let inputJSON = Array.from(new FormData(myForm))
      .reduce((r,[name,value])=>{ r[name]=value; return r} ,{}) 
    
  console.log(inputJSON) 
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <input name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" required> <br>
  <input name="Password"  type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required> <br>
  <input name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required> <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <button type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Jackhamer secure for what ? that's not in the question. you may use a https connexion